# Calculating $\frac{f'(e)}{f(e)}$ for $f(x) = x^{x^{x}}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, contest-math

Define $f(x) = x^{x^{x}}$

Compute $\frac{f'(e)}{f(e)}$.

I have an answer, but I do not know how to reach this answer. The correct answer is: **$e^{e-1}+2e^e$**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{d}{dx}\ln f(x) 
$$
Since $\ln f(x) = x^x \ln(x)$, the product rule gives
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} =\frac{d(x^x)}{dx}\ln x + \frac{x^x}{x}
$$
We can use $x^x = e^{x\ln x}$ to get $d(x^x)/dx = x^x(1+\ln x)$, which brings us to
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} =x^x(1+\ln x)\ln x + x^{x-1}
$$
Plugging in $e$ then gives your answer.

Comment: Thank you, this explains what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

We let $f (x)=x^{x^{x}} $. Then we have $$f'(x)=x^{x^{x}} \frac {d}{dx}[x^x \ln x] $$ $$=x^{x^{x}} [ \frac{d}{dx}(x^x)\ln x +x^x \frac {d}{dx}(\ln x)] $$ $$=x^{x^{x}}[x^x \ln x(\ln x+1)+x^{x-1}] $$ Hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

$
f(x) = x^{x^x} \\
\implies \ln f = x^x \ln x \\
\implies \frac{d}{dx} \ln f = \ln x \frac{d}{dx} (x^x) + (x^x) \frac{d}{dx} (\ln x) \\
\implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = x^x \ln x (1 + \ln x) + x^{x - 1}.
$